# Rails3: rewrite url_for for subdomain support, how to extend action mailer to use such url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I take code from [Subdomain RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

```
module UrlHelper
  def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
    [subdomain, request.domain, request.port_string].join
  end

  def url_for(options = nil)
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
      options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
    end
    super
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include UrlHelper
end
```

It is ok to use modified `url_for` in views of Controllers. But I have trouble with ActionMailer.

I tried to use following:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  include UrlHelper
end
```

But ActionMailer views still use old unmodified url_for from ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.

What is the best practice to add new url_for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following code to the file app/helpers/url_helper.rb:

```
def set_mailer_url_options
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = with_subdomain(request.subdomain)
end
```

and modify the file app/controllers/application_controller.rb to add:

```
before_filter :set_mailer_url_options
```

[Source](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise/wiki/Tutorial-%28Walkthrough%29)

Comment: Not thread-safe, it's better to use less elegant, but more bullet-proof solution: actionmailer-with-request

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/10/actionmailer-and-host-value/ - details here

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this issue but I don't think it is still the best way to do it.  I have tried and will still try to come up with a better solution but here is what I have done in my email template. The reason I put this in the email template is because I'm using Devise, but I'm hoping to come up with something better.

```
subdomain = @resource.account.subdomain
subdomain = (subdomain || "")
subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
host = [subdomain, ActionMailer::Base::default_url_options[:host]].join
```

You can pass the host to the url_for now like this

```
user_confirmation_url(:host => host)
```

Comment: I want to rewrite url_for for action mailer. Similar to action controller

Comment: Well I basically embedded the code above into the view layer so I would imagine you could do the same in the controller.  So you could move the UrlHelper code as methods in your Notifier controller and try it...again not the best solution but might get you by for now.  I'm still doing alot of work on this and if I come up with something I'll let you know.  It appears that the ActionMailer almost requires you to pass in the host and doesn't rewrite like the Controllers do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest solution on Rails 3.0.x was to construct the host-with-subdomain manually in every URL in my mailer views.  For example:

```
Your account is here:

<%= account_url(:host => "#{@account.subdomain}.#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}" %>
```

-- where your `@account` model knows its subdomain.

This in nice and simple, threadsafe, and isolated.  You don't need to pollute other parts of your codebase.  And it's easy to back out once you move to Rails 3.1.x, which should handle all this automatically I believe.